# iOS5 Storyboard how to pop to some view controller

Tags: iphone, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I'm using a storyboard with push segues. 
Here's my setup:

Select User ->pushes tabBarController ->pushes add event -> pushes 2nd part of add event

I'm trying to make the 2nd part of the add event to return to the tab bar once the user completes the action.

If I use

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The app returns to the select user page, and crashes with EXC_bad_access when I try to push the tab bar again.

I'm trying to figure out if I can use:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:<#(UIViewController *)#> animated:YES];
```

To handle the transition, but I'm not sure how I would return to the tab bar.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obvious solution is to have access to your tabBarController instance from 2nd part controller (you can pass reference through 1stPartController or make tabBarController singleton) and use

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:tabBarControllerInstance animated:YES];
```